# vim: keep cursor position when switching mode

Tags: vim

I'm trying to remap the F1 key to remove search highlighting.  This is simple in normal mode:

```
nmap <F1> :noh<CR>
```

but in insert mode its a little more tricky.  I can do

```
imap <F1> <ESC>:noh<CR>i
```

but that causes the cursor to move backward one slot.  A minor annoyance, but still an annoyance.  I've tried adding a `<RIGHT>`, but if I do that before the `i` it will shift to the next line if I'm at the end of the current one, and if I do it after the `i` it will shift to the second character if I'm at the beginning of the line.

Is there a way to make it do what I want?  Really all I want is for the F1 key to remove search highlighting in all modes.  Don't much care how that happens so it there's a better solution, let me know.

Comment: As an addition to the answers, keep in mind that there is also `gi` - Insert text in the same position as where Insert mode was stopped last time in the current buffer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avoid to use `<esc>` if you don't want your cursor to move. Use `<c-o>` instead.

```
" NB: this mapping doesn't remove, but toggles search highlighting,
" which is often much more useful

" Normal Mode
nnoremap <silent> <F8> :set hlsearch!<bar>set hlsearch?<CR>
" Insert Mode
imap     <silent> <F8> <c-o><F8>
" (strict?) Visual Mode (i.e Select Mode is excluded)
xmap     <silent> <F8> <c-\><c-n><F8>gv
" Select Mode
smap     <silent> <F8> <c-\><c-n><F8>gv<c-g>
```

Comment: will this work the same if I just copy the `imap` line to `nmap`, `vmap`, etc?

Comment: this caused a whole mess of crap to happen.  I can't really describe it, but it obliterated the entire file.  I had to quite vim and reload to get the file back.

Comment: You don't need `nmap`, there is already  `nnoremap` which say: "I don't rely on other mappings, fear no interferences". Regarding `:xmap`, you'll have to escape (`<C-\><C-n>`) then reselect (`gv`). Regarding `:smap`, the reselection needs to be achieved with `gv<c-g>`

Comment: ??? Have you typed `nmap <F8> whatever<F8>` ? This would be a recursive mapping and definitively not what you want.

Comment: it's possible that it broke because i user `nmap` again.  It's working now with just the two lines you suggested.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `<C-o>` to execute a single command from insert mode:

```
imap <F1> <C-o>:noh<CR>
```